# java error: <identifier> expected, not sure how to fix

Tags: java

I'm sifting through some old open source java program and am trying to get it to compile and run. Among my many list of errors is this one:

```
java:178: error: <identifier> expected
cons = reflector.getConstructor((Class[])null);
    ^
java:178: error: cannot find symbol
cons = reflector.getConstructor((Class[])null);
^
symbol: class cons
location: class XMLMapTransformer
```

The method in question is this:

```
private Object unmarshalClass(Class reflector, Node node)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
               InvocationTargetException {
        Constructor cons = null;
        try {            
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            cons = reflector.getConstructor((Class[])null);
        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        Object o = cons.newInstance((Class)null);
        Node n;

        Method[] methods = reflector.getMethods();
        NamedNodeMap nnm = node.getAttributes();

        if (nnm != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nnm.getLength(); i++) {
                n = nnm.item(i);

                try {
                    int j = reflectFindMethodByName(reflector,
                            "set" + n.getNodeName());
                    if (j >= 0) {
                        reflectInvokeMethod(o,methods[j],
                                new String [] {n.getNodeValue()});
                    } else {
                        logger.warn("Unsupported attribute '" +
                                n.getNodeName() +
                                "' on <" + node.getNodeName() + "> tag");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return o;
    }
```

Any idea as to fixing this issue? I can provide more details or a link to source if required.

Comment: Wild guess: move annotation above method?

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Jan is the man, moving it above the method worked.

Comment: but why doesn't it work above the assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation can annotate Classes, Member variables and Methods. You cannot put them into method body - this is syntactically incorrect. Move Annotation above method and you're fine.